# Javascript doesn't output in the right Div

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have three separate JS scripts pulling data out of three different JSON files.

I declare the divs at the top of the page and execute the script. Each one points to a different div with a document.getElementById function.

It doesn´t work and I´m struggling to understand why. The 3 JSON are parsed correctly but the output is stacked together *after* the divs I've declared at the top.

```
<body onload="op();">

    <h2>1</h2>
    <div id="myData2"></div>
    <h2>2</h2>
    <div id="myData"></div>
    <h2>3</h2>
    <div id="myData3"></div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-half">
                                <script>
                        fetch('top.json')
                            .then(function (response) {
                                return response.json();
                            })
                            .then(function (data) {
                                appendData(data);
                            })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                                console.log('error: ' + err);
                            });
                        function appendData(data) {
                            var mainContainer1 = document.getElementById("myData");
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.data.children.length; i++) {
                                var div = document.createElement("div");
                                div.innerHTML = data.data.children[i].data.title;
                                mainContainer1.appendChild(div);
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-half">

                    <script>
                            fetch('top.json')
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    return response.json();
                                })
                                .then(function (data2) {
                                    appendData(data2);
                                })
                                .catch(function (err) {
                                    console.log('error: ' + err);
                                });
                            function appendData(data2) {
                                var mainContainer2 = document.getElementById("myData2");
                                for (var i = 0; i < data2.data.children.length; i++) {
                                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                                    div.innerHTML = data2.data.children[i].data.title;
                                    mainContainer2.appendChild(div);
                                }

                            }

                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-half">
                    <script>
                            fetch('local3.json')
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    return response.json();
                                })
                                .then(function (data2) {
                                    appendData(data2);
                                })
                                .catch(function (err) {
                                    console.log('error: ' + err);
                                });
                            function appendData(data2) {
                                var mainContainer3 = document.getElementById("myData3");
                                for (var i = 0; i < data2.data.children.length; i++) {
                                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                                    div.innerHTML = data2.data.children[i].data.title;
                                    mainContainer3.appendChild(div);
                                }
                            }
                    </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because you _overwrite_ your function `appendData` multiple times …

Comment: This doesn’t need any named functions to begin with, you can just put the code into `.then(function (data2) { … })` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is lies under this line:

```js
.then(function(data) {
  appendData(data);
})
```

Since **your all functions got the same name, the `appendData(data);` will always invoke the same `function`** which is the below one:

```js
function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer1 = document.getElementById("myData");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.data.children.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = data.data.children[i].data.title;
    mainContainer1.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

Then your data will stick in the same place as always.

So for solving this, **you don't have to use different function each time and then call them within your `.then` you just can make it easier by doing your functional things within your `.then`** just like this:

```js
.then(function(data) {
  var mainContainer1 = document.getElementById("myData");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.data.children.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = data.data.children[i].data.title;
    mainContainer1.appendChild(div);
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks @smakss this makes so much sense now. I though I was getting something wrong in the html and totally overlooked the json functions... thanks!